# Failed to connect to the supercomputer platform using vscode ssh-remote

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, supercomputers

When I used vscode ssh-remote to connect to the Dawning 6000 supercomputer platform, the log file reported the following error:

```
[2023-09-08 09:23:49] error This machine not meet Visual Studio Code Server's prerequisites, expected either...:   - find GLIBC >= 2.17 (but found v1.1.0 instead) for GNU environments
  - find /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1, which is required to run the Visual Studio Code Server in musl environments
```

I have tried to install.vscode-server offline but still report the same error, can someone help me solve this problem?

I have successfully connected to the server using MobaXterm, but would like to use vscode to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to downgrade vscode. I had the same problem but not on your cluster. Otherwise contact your sys admins